# Downloading subtitles from OpenSubtitles in Delphi or C++ Builder?

Tags: delphi, download, c++builder, xml-rpc

I would like to download a subtitles for a movie using OpenSubtitles API but cannot find a complete working example anywhere. Only thing I found was this:

http://www.yanniel.info/2012/01/open-subtitles-api-in-delphi.html

I did everything what here says but it is incomplete. I log in and find a subtitle but don't know how to finally download a file?

Edit: This is what I did so far;

```
unit OpensubtitlesAPI;

interface

uses
  IdHTTP, Classes, SysUtils;

  function LogIn(aUsername, aPassword,
                 aLanguage, aUserAgent: string): string;
  function LogOut(aToken: string): string;
  function SearchSubtitles(aToken, aSublanguageID,
                           aMovieHash: string;
                           aMovieByteSize: Cardinal): string;  overload;
  function SearchSubtitles(aToken, aSublanguageID: string;
                           aImdbID: Cardinal): string; overload;
  function SearchSubtitles(aToken, aSublanguageID,
                           aQuery: string): string;  overload;

implementation

function XML_RPC(aRPCRequest: string): string;
const
  cURL= 'http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc';
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Source,
  ResponseContent: TStringStream;
begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
  lHTTP.Request.Accept := '*/*';
  lHTTP.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
  lHTTP.Request.Method := 'POST';
  lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'OS Test User Agent';
  Source := TStringStream.Create(aRPCRequest);
  ResponseContent:= TStringStream.Create;
  try
    try
      lHTTP.Post(cURL, Source, ResponseContent);
      Result:= ResponseContent.DataString;
    except
      Result:= '';
    end;
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
    Source.Free;
    ResponseContent.Free;
  end;
end;

function LogIn(aUsername, aPassword, aLanguage, aUserAgent: string): string;
const
  LOG_IN = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
           '<methodCall>' +
           '  <methodName>LogIn</methodName>' +
           '  <params>'   +
           '    <param>'  +
           '      <value><string>%0:s</string></value>' +
           '    </param>' +
           '    <param>'  +
           '      <value><string>%1:s</string></value>' +
           '    </param>' +
           '    <param>'  +
           '      <value><string>%2:s</string></value>' +
           '    </param>' +
           '    <param>'  +
           '      <value><string>%3:s</string></value>' +
           '    </param>' +
           '  </params>'  +
           '</methodCall>';
begin
  //TODO: XML Encoding
  Result:= XML_RPC(Format(LOG_IN, [aUsername, aPassword, aLanguage, aUserAgent]));
end;

function LogOut(aToken: string): string;
const
  LOG_OUT = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
           '<methodCall>' +
           '  <methodName>LogOut</methodName>' +
           '  <params>'   +
           '    <param>'  +
           '      <value><string>%0:s</string></value>' +
           '    </param>' +
           '  </params>'  +
           '</methodCall>';
begin
  //TODO: XML Encoding
  Result:= XML_RPC(Format(LOG_OUT, [aToken]));
end;

function SearchSubtitles(aToken, aSublanguageID, aMovieHash: string; aMovieByteSize: Cardinal): string;
const
  SEARCH_SUBTITLES = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
                     '<methodCall>' +
                     '  <methodName>SearchSubtitles</methodName>' +
                     '  <params>' +
                     '    <param>' +
                     '      <value><string>%0:s</string></value>' +
                     '    </param>' +
                     '  <param>' +
                     '   <value>' +
                     '    <array>' +
                     '     <data>' +
                     '      <value>' +
                     '       <struct>' +
                     '        <member>' +
                     '         <name>sublanguageid</name>' +
                     '         <value><string>%1:s</string>' +
                     '         </value>' +
                     '        </member>' +
                     '        <member>' +
                     '         <name>moviehash</name>' +
                     '         <value><string>%2:s</string></value>' +
                     '        </member>' +
                     '        <member>' +
                     '         <name>moviebytesize</name>' +
                     '         <value><double>%3:d</double></value>' +
                     '        </member>' +
                     '       </struct>' +
                     '      </value>' +
                     '     </data>' +
                     '    </array>' +
                     '   </value>' +
                     '  </param>' +
                     ' </params>' +
                     '</methodCall>';

begin
  //TODO: XML Encoding
  Result:= XML_RPC(Format(SEARCH_SUBTITLES, [aToken, aSublanguageID, aMovieHash, aMovieByteSize]));
end;

function SearchSubtitles(aToken, aSublanguageID: string;
  aImdbID: Cardinal): string;
const
  SEARCH_SUBTITLES = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
                     '<methodCall>' +
                     '  <methodName>SearchSubtitles</methodName>' +
                     '  <params>' +
                     '    <param>' +
                     '      <value><string>%0:s</string></value>' +
                     '    </param>' +
                     '  <param>' +
                     '   <value>' +
                     '    <array>' +
                     '     <data>' +
                     '      <value>' +
                     '       <struct>' +
                     '        <member>' +
                     '         <name>sublanguageid</name>' +
                     '         <value><string>%1:s</string>' +
                     '         </value>' +
                     '        </member>' +
                     '        <member>' +
                     '         <name>imdbid</name>' +
                     '         <value><string>%2:d</string></value>' +
                     '        </member>' +
                     '       </struct>' +
                     '      </value>' +
                     '     </data>' +
                     '    </array>' +
                     '   </value>' +
                     '  </param>' +
                     ' </params>' +
                     '</methodCall>';

begin
  //TODO: XML Encoding
  Result:= XML_RPC(Format(SEARCH_SUBTITLES, [aToken, aSublanguageID, aImdbID]));
end;

function SearchSubtitles(aToken, aSublanguageID,
  aQuery: string): string;
const
  SEARCH_SUBTITLES = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
                     '<methodCall>' +
                     '  <methodName>SearchSubtitles</methodName>' +
                     '  <params>' +
                     '    <param>' +
                     '      <value><string>%0:s</string></value>' +
                     '    </param>' +
                     '  <param>' +
                     '   <value>' +
                     '    <array>' +
                     '     <data>' +
                     '      <value>' +
                     '       <struct>' +
                     '        <member>' +
                     '         <name>sublanguageid</name>' +
                     '         <value><string>%1:s</string>' +
                     '         </value>' +
                     '        </member>' +
                     '        <member>' +
                     '         <name>query</name>' +
                     '         <value><string>%2:s</string></value>' +
                     '        </member>' +
                     '       </struct>' +
                     '      </value>' +
                     '     </data>' +
                     '    </array>' +
                     '   </value>' +
                     '  </param>' +
                     ' </params>' +
                     '</methodCall>';

begin
  //TODO: XML Encoding
  Result:= XML_RPC(Format(SEARCH_SUBTITLES, [aToken, aSublanguageID, aQuery]));
end;
end.
```

And finally, I used C++ Builder to do next:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    UnicodeString response = LogIn("", "", "en", "OS Test User Agent");
    XMLDocument1->XML->Text = response;
    XMLDocument1->Active = true;
    UnicodeString token = XMLDocument1->ChildNodes->Nodes[1]->GetChildNodes()->Nodes[0]->
                  GetChildNodes()->Nodes[0]->GetChildNodes()->Nodes[0]->
                  GetChildNodes()->Nodes[0]->GetChildNodes()->Nodes[0]->
                  GetChildNodes()->Nodes[1]->GetChildNodes()->Nodes[0]->
                  GetText();
    Memo1->Text = SearchSubtitles(token, "en", "7d9cd5def91c9432", 735934464);
    LogOut(token);
}
```

When I execute this I get a response like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodResponse>
<params>
 <param>
  <value>
   <struct>
    <member>
     <name>status</name>
     <value>
      <string>200 OK</string>
     </value>
    </member>
    <member>
     <name>data</name>
     <value>
      <boolean>0</boolean>
     </value>
    </member>
    <member>
     <name>seconds</name>
     <value>
      <double>0.008</double>
     </value>
    </member>
   </struct>
  </value>
 </param>
</params>
</methodResponse>
```

So, what's next? How to get the file (subtitles) location?
Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is a place for asking specific questions related to specific problems. It is **not** a place to ask others to do all your work for you without pay. I suggest you either seek a paid employee to do this for you, or you ask another question regarding an actual problem.

Comment: @LaKraven I did submit what I found and said I managed to get it work, but cannot finish it. That said, I only need someone to show me how to download a subtitle file.

Comment: @Tracer your answer specifically states "Could someone please provide a full working example?" ergo you are asking for someone to do the work for you.

Comment: @Tracer, first you need to get a XML parser and parse the responses. That's what is completely missing in that code. If you do this, then you'll be able to properly get the login token, search the subtitles and it that search response you'll find the `SubDownloadLink` and `ZipDownloadLink` attributes. I'll try to prepare an example, but now I'm busy with my job and if this question won't get closed I'll post some code sample.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you're downloading subtitles or something else, it's the same code. Having a different question on stack overflow for EVERY different thing you might download, is dumb. Downvote and vote to close, and PLEASE think about other people when you ask questions, and read the FAQ, Tracer.  It's for your good and everyone elses.

Comment: @Warren, *"think about other people"* is somehow counterargument. The code from the link in the question is not even quarter of what you need to do to communicate with that server. StackOverflow has a very good web search optimization, so if someone will search for this topic, s/he can get here, not to the site with that incomplete code. I definitely agree that this question doesn't belong here because of..., but it might get answer. Now it will remain unanswered... Anyway, you have also asked a few quite *"personal"* questions ;-)

Comment: @Tracer, edit your question by providing details of what you've already gotten working and which parts you need help on. Remove the request for a full working example, give specifics  on what's not working and post snippets of your code. Do this and I think you'll get a better response.

Comment: I edited the first post.

Comment: Up voted for good edits. Question is now specific and shows effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was: OpenSubtitles requires country code with 3 characters ("eng" instead of "en").